# Does helm update status after the underlying deployments are deleted?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Lets consider a scenario,
I have a chart mychart-1.0 which is deployed.

```
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                     STATUS      CHART                                   APP VERSION
mychart-1.0      test-ns       1        2020-06-10 22:49:40.700756598 -0700 -0700   deployed    nucleus-service-deployment-chart-1.0.0
```

This created kubernetes pods and deployments in test-ns namespace. 
I have deleted the pods and deployments using **kubectl delete**. 
The **STATUS** in helm list command still shows deployed. Is this supposed to be or something is wrong?

Comment: No, it's working as expected.

Comment: By expected you mean that it doesn't update the status in helm list?

Comment: yes, when you deploy something using `helm`, it is also expected that you will only apply changes using `helm insatall/update/delete ...`.

Comment: @RohitUB Does it solve your question?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks @KamolHasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kubernetes resources created by Helm should be managed by Helm .Even if you delete the Deployment or any other resources Helm status will be shown deployed.
If you try to do Helm upgrade it will again create those deleted deployment.
Whatever you do with the resources after creating from Helm, it doesn't matter,Helm will show `deployed` always unless changed via helm commands